# multiply and sum two columns in two dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, multiplication

I have two dataframes both with 6 rows. I want to multiply the values in two selected columns from the two dataframes (one from each df)

```
result = sum(a * b for a, b in zip(list(df1['col1']), list(df2['col3'])))
```

I do not seem to get what I want. I did the calc "manually" in Excel (for one date in my time series), which gave me the expected result. So my question is if I did  something wrong?

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question?

Comment: you can merge or concatenate the two data frames then use apply with a function to set the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will can just use pandas abstractions for it.

```
result = df['col1'] * df['col3']
```

If then you want to get the sum of those result values you can just do:

```
sum(results)
```

Answer (score 2):

If same number of rows and same indices simple subtract and then use `sum`:

```
result = (df1['col1'] * df2['col3']).sum()
```

If possible different indices but same length:

```
result  = (df1['col1'] * df2['col3'].to_numpy()).sum()
```

Or use [`numpy.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

```
result = np.dot(df1['col1'],  df2['col3'])
```

---

If possible different length and different indices:

```
result = (df1['col1'].reset_index(drop=True)
             .mul(df2['col3'].reset_index(drop=True), fill_value=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

result = np.matmul(df1.col1, df2.col1)
```

This will also sum the multiplications.

Your formulation works too, if you add []:

```
result = sum([a * b for a, b in zip(list(df1['col1']), list(df2['col1']))])
```

This gives the same result.